# ASP.NET Handler not working properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ashx

I created an Ashx handler in C# that serves me up images based on a `fileid` parameter that gets passed on to me. I also have a simple tooltip preview script that I wrote, which is not working. You can see the image loading, but then after it loads, the image just vanishes.

I suspect the issue is in the ASHX handler because if I use a static image, it works just fine. Here is my ASHX handler code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fileId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString["fileId"] ?? "") ?? "";
        string fullFileName = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads") + "\\" + fileId;

        using (FileStream s = File.Open(fullFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = HelperClasses.Utility.GetMimeTypeFromMagic(fullFileName);

            var buffer = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(buffer, 0, (int) s.Length);

            context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            context.Response.Write(buffer);

            s.Close();
        }
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Close();
    }
```

In addition, I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/543qbx71/) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: hey i think its this issue with chrome, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219565/iis-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding

Comment: Your handler is fine; if I plug the URL into a browser I get the image.

Comment: Does `GetMimeTypeFromMagic` (awesome method name btw) return the correct content type?

Comment: It works fine in `IE`...

Comment: In your handler, replace the line `context.Response.Close();` with `context.Response.End();` and see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: @JawwadAlam -- That was the problem! It works great now! Make an answer out of your comment and I will accept it.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange - The files I have do not retain an extension, so I don't know what kind of file it is, so the `GetMimeTypeFromMagic` function will look at the header and the magic bytes to determine the file type (hence the name). I also have a sister function called `GetExtensionFromMagic` that does something similar, but returns the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the line

`context.Response.Close();`

is the issue. The close method abruptly ends the response stream, see details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx) and also check this related question [IIS & Chrome: failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219565/iis-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding)

Replace the line with `context.Response.End();` to normally end the response.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing garbage at the end of the response, specifically because you are calling `Response.Write` in addition to `BinaryWrite`. If you look at the response of your handler, this is at the end (literally):

> System.Byte[]

[image]

Obviously that isn't part of the image. This line should be removed:

```
context.Response.Write(buffer);
```

I would also [avoid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx) doing anything like `Response.End` and `Response.Close`. Let the ASP.NET runtime take care of that.

Better yet, if you are using the .NET Framework 4 or older, you can simplify the whole thing to this:

```
s.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```