# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when trying to show PHP page

Tags: php, html

I have a page that loads a list of data rows via a foreach loop. The code goes something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($data as $datarow){ ?>
       //data displayed here. about 10 hidden fields and then <tr>'s with 8 <td>'s each
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i run on my local machine (with IIS), this renders fine. even if there are more than 20,000 elements in $data

But when i publish to server and try to run this, i get the following error in chrome debugger: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING. Even when $data has about 500 elements. EDIT: anything below 500 works fine

Does anyone know how i can solve this error? do i have to increase the value of a setting on my IIS server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run phpinfo(); Please check that your memory_limit is set to a healthy number or mirrors your local environment variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219565/iis-chrome-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding

Comment: I saw that but its not very helpful in my case.

Comment: memory_limit is set to 128M