# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: google-chrome, laravel, nginx, debian, php-5.6

I've been having some problems with my application not loading the views (sometimes).
I am running a Debian server with php-fpm and nginx (php5.6.8 and nginx 1.8.0) Both compiled from source. On top of that I am running Lavavel 4.2.

So far I've had the problem in both Chrome and Firefox (chrome simply stops loading and shows the error, firefox does not show an error but shows a incomplete version of the view).

So far I've checked the permissions of both nginx and PHP, they both run as the same user (www-data:www-data).
My php-fpm socket is configured as:

```
[sitename]

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/sitename.sock
listen.backlog = -1
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode=0660

; Unix user/group of processes
user = folderuser
group = www-data

; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 75
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 500

; Pass environment variables
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Note that I set user to folderuser because the folder where the files for the site are located is owned by folderuser (folderuser:www-data).
Furthermore, permissions inside laravel folders are configured as 755 (775 for cache and upload folders so that www-data can write cache files)

I have disabled any kind of serverside php cache (except for zend opcache).

I've also tried disabling "prefetch resources to load pages more quickly" feature in chrome, which did not solve the problem.

As a last resort I've tried this solution:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Fix for Chrome / PHP 5.4 issue
| http://laravel.io/forum/02-08-2014-another-problem-only-with-chrome
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

App::after(function($request, $response)
{

    $content = $response->getContent();

    $contentLength = strlen($content);

    $response->header('Content-Length', $contentLength);

});
```

And some variants to this script, but I got some content length mismatches (more often than the `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` errors.

So to sum up, I've checked permissions and user/group settings serverside, I've disabled serverside caching (except for zend), I've messed around with chrome settings and I've tried a script for laravel, none of which solved the issue I am having. Note that the issue happens at random intervals at random pages on the site.

I really do not know what the next step towards solving my problem would be as the solutions above are the only ones I've found on the internet.

I would really appreciate some help.

**Edit:** I have a beta version of the same application running off another server with the exact same configuration (only difference is in hardware, more memory though), the issue does not present there.

Also, I forgot the mention that the application does not run with HTTPS (currently). The beta version however is running with HTTPS.

**Edit** The server where the issue is present has 2048 MB RAM, the beta server has 8192 MB RAM.

**Edit** I inspected the response with fiddler when the error occured, it simply cuts of the response at some point for no reason.

Comment: it was low RAM issue in my case. After increase from 2GB to 8GB the same issue as yours but during moodle installation (resource heavy) was gone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might want to check if the folder `/var/lib/nginx` is owned by `www-data` too. I had this problem that, when the response page was too big, the Nginx worker process tried to use this folder and failed, because it was owned by `nginx` and the worker process ran under `www-data`. By doing `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx`, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent a lot of hours trying to figure out this. It fixed for me a lot of problems I was facing

Comment: Same deal I had to update my user and group in nginx.conf as well, it was resetting.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this in the future, my `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` were as a result of having run out of space. Have a look at your disk usage and see if that's why!

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990521/12553450

Comment: @mafei Are you suggesting I additionally answer there? Could be a good idea, as long as it's not considered spamming

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar problem on my Nginx Server running on the latest Debian. I'm running a Wordpress site with Advanced Custom Fields installed. On the advanced custom fields it says that the problem could potentially be with the max_input_vars value in the php.ini file. I increased my value from 1000 to 3000 and that fixed the issue on one of my sites.

You can check out this link to see if it might help you. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/faq/limit-number-fields/