# net::err incomplete chunked encoding error - Spring sseEmiter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, events, server-sent-events

ive implemented a spring sseEmitter to send a very basic message as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/events/broadcast", method =RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter broadcastMessage() throws IOException{
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();
    sseEmitter.send("Message 1");
    sseEmitter.complete();
    return sseEmitter;


}
```

Client side:

```
 var source = new EventSource("/events/broadcast");
    source.onmessage = function(event){
        var i = 0;
    }
```

However upon running, the method gets called however I receive the following error in my browser:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/events/broadcast net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

I figure its to do with browser settings because the code is consistent across other examples.

Any experience with resolving this kind of error would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Do you have a running anti-virus?

Comment: im on my company's network which probably has a lot of anti-* software

Comment: May be you are facing the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If so, please post how.