# What causes "unexpectedly closed the connection ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

Accessing my test.php in a local server environment, and chrome will not load the page.

```
<?php
  virtual('./database_functions.php');

  echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
  echo "<body>";
  echo "<p>Hello World"</p>;
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `virtual` and not `include`/`require`?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error

Comment: Dreamweaver put it in the file. It's for relative referencing so I kept it?
Can you tell me why you are asking? Why would I *not* use it?

Comment: Oy, another reason to not like Dreamweaver. [Here is the documentation on virtual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php), basically it's making an apache call, and not inserting the unprocessed code you need into your script. You need to use either [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) (I'd personally go for `require_once`), which would put the PHP code in exactly as you created it.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Apparently Dreamweaver uses it for relative referencing depending on site configuration.

I've gone back to using raw text writing my HTML and PHP because Dreamweaver is such a bloated POS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the script from command line php I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function virtual() in /var/www/test.php on line 2
```

This simply illustrates a new question.

Google searching reveals that include/require/require_once is recommended, however, I'd like to understand why virtual is being problematic.

It's not so much getting the right answer as understanding *why* virtual() is being problematic.

EDIT: Blame Dreamweaver. Explained by @aynber