# Sometimes error appears net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: php, laravel

My website is build in Laravel. when i load my site, sometimes it loads ok and sometimes it shows error message in console `"net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"` and page content doesn't load. This error only appears in `Chrome console`. In `firefox`, it doesnt show any error in console, but doesn't load the page either. Can anyone suggest any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Have you cheked this out ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429848/5844171

Comment: Yes , i checked that link. nginx not installed on my server and i tried few other solutions mentioned in link, but none of those worked.