# Guzzle runs into ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, guzzle6

I'm trying access external API with guzzle, but keep running into ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING. How do I solve this?

Comment: Maybe this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error

Comment: Stupid me was trying to access response without `getBody()`

Comment: Edmund if you figured it out please write an answer explaining the solution and then after I think 24 hours you can accept it as the correct answer.  Thanks!