# Why my API throws ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have a REST API build using Java 8 and Spring Boot. The API is used to download files. I was using Spring Boot's `StreamingResponseBody` class to send the file as a stream of Data.

The full code snippet can be found below:

`StreamingResponseBody resp = new StreamingResponseBody() {
     @Override
     public void writeTo(final OutputStream output) throws IOException {
         try {
             Files.copy(myFile.toPath(), output);
         } finally {
             output.close();
             boolean check = myFile.delete();
             log.info("File {} deletion status : {}", myFile.getAbsolutePath(), check);
         }
     }
 };`

`HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + myFile.getName());
 headers.add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");`

`return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(resp, headers, HttpStatus.OK);`

The API is giving correct response for some requests, but for few cases it throws **ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING** error.
I tried looking into many places but was not able to fix this issue.
I am trying to call the API from an Angular 8 Web App to download a file. The issue comes for all the major browsers available, I tested using IE 11, Chrome, Firefox, Edge.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error and in which cases the error is throwed?

Comment: I have checked the answer, and the issue is happening in local systems as well as when the application is deployed to our in house server. I have checked from other people&#39;s system also, issue occurs there too, but it is inconsistent, happening randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the output.close().

I reviewed some samples and no body close the output. Spring should close it after the request.

Also I advice you, stress your app in order to detect unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when `spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.2.1.RELEASE` dependency was added.

After a lot of search of what was miss-configured an **upgrade** of the entire project to `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.5.RELEASE` (that also upgraded to spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.5.RELEASE) fixed everything. With this upgrade the response was still chunked but properly interpreted by browser.

From these symptoms I think it was a bug in the way chunked response (http2 specific) was handled by spring. It was too hard to pinpoint the exact problem and we moved over with spring upgraded.