# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, adonis.js

I am using adonuxt (adonis.js, nuxt.js), my project works locally nicely but it doesn't work fully in live server. My node version in local and live server is same as well. for some reason one file is not loading and getting failed error in the console.
`_nuxt/ebb219c99f71342c880d.js net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)`

for this reason, all buttons click events is not working so the site loads but no events are working.

Anyone knows the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome net::ERR\_INCOMPLETE\_CHUNKED\_ENCODING error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894154/chrome-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-error)

Comment: nope. it's different

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I updated Nginx, to resolve it I had to disable buffering in Nginx.

```
location /{
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Replace with your Nuxt.js server url
  proxy_buffering off;
  # other proxy settings...
}
```

Nginx buffering can interfere with the chunked encoding process.
I hope this helps.