# Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined at window.onload

Tags: swagger-ui, hapi, hapi-swagger

In my localhost, my swagger UI working well. localhost:3030/documentation
This UI was working on the server also but from today on the server it is not working https://digitalpathshalabd.com/documentation

Errors

[image: img_error]

Comment: Did you server configuration change? The `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` error is not from Swagger UI. See if this helps: [Chrome net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29894154/113116)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same "SwaggerUIBundle is not defined" with a blank page. Also the problem only on server and not local. And it also had worked in the past.
Then when I **ctrl**+f5 the local swagger page, it then also appeared local.

For us it appeared the Configuration order was swapped.
For me the fix was moving app.UseRouting() after the swagger init

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{                                    
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Procedure Service V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = "";
    });
    app.UseRouting();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9 version and was facing this problem.

I checked https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui and added maven dependency for a lower swagger-ui version 3.0.21

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

I found that the "swagger-ui/index.html" does not reference "swagger-initializer.js" , instead its source code is present in index.html itself (this the boiler-plate referring to pet store)

So in my Spring boot classpath resources/public folder, I copied the older swagger dist index.html file (which has the initializer code) and did the following changes

1. Changed the url part to point to my api-docs url. (e.g. /v3/api-docs)
2. Added "swagger-ui" to the src references, so that the swagger bundles/js will be called successfully from my index.html

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="./swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
<script charset="UTF-8" src="./swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
```

3. When I accessed index.html - http://{server}:{port}/index.html- I could access my local Open API doc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your swagger middleware configured correctly?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
     services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>  
     {  
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });                  
     });  
     services.AddControllers();  
}
```

This adds the Swagger generator to the services collection.
In the Configure() method, let’s enable the middleware for serving the generated JSON document and the Swagger UI:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)  
{  
     app.UseSwagger();  
     // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),  
     // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.  
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>  
     {  
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");  
     });  
}
```