# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING in IE & ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, axd

I use IExplorer 11 in Windows 8.1, and IIS and ASP.NET 4.6.1 in Windows Server 2008 R2.

My ASP.NET application is **WebForms** and using **UpdatePanels**.

I have handlers config:

```
<httpHandlers>

  <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
  <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
  <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
  <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
```

and **system.webServer.handlers**:

```
  <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" 
       verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" 
       preCondition="integratedMode" 
       type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Now, I tried to access my web application via HTTPS.
But I get an error now, before not, another older tests was right.

I get error in Console (F12 for Developers in IE):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

Full message in Console:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> ScriptResource.axd?d=JdegD_7PUJVmXULFjUEnn8-WKsu7dMZfODGKttl…:5  POST
>   https://myHostname.company.es/v2/Access/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fv2%2f
>   net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.executeRequest @
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=JdegD_7PUJVmXULFjUEnn8-WKsu7dMZfODGKttl…:5
>
> Sys.Net._WebRequestManager.executeRequest @
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=JdegD_7PUJVmXULFjUEnn8-WKsu7dMZfODGKttl…:5
>
> Sys.Net.WebRequest.invoke @
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=JdegD_7PUJVmXULFjUEnn8-WKsu7dMZfODGKttl…:5
>
> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmit @
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=xK_C6ZiWnJAwbFmxycomhSoVuG7wQBL347wu7B8vRv4lZ-am5E4rxJ-GZ-gWm03a7M6T4lFWxdjOei…:5
>
> (anonymous function) @
>   ScriptResource.axd?d=JdegD_7PUJVmXULFjUEnn8-WKsu7dMZfODGKttl…:5b

I try using

> scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true"

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <!-- Test: Error net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING -->
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true" />

    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

and I try disabled **compression**:

```
<!-- DISABLED GZIP 

  Test: Error net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" sendCacheHeaders="true" cacheControlHeader="max-age=31536000" dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="90" staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="90" dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="0" staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="0">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionLevel="10" staticCompressionLevel="10"/>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
-->
```

Any suggestions? How-to do good troubleshooting about it ?

**UPDATE**: 
I test in Chrome, and I get the same error.

I have seen F12 Console log:

**Headers**

> Cache-Control:no-cache
>
> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 
>   Origin:http://myhostname.company.es
>   Referer:http://myhostname.company.es/v2/Access/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fv2%2f
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
>
> X-MicrosoftAjax:Delta=true
>
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

**Form Data**

> ```
> ...
> __ASYNCPOST:true
> ```

I haven't any antivirus in local

Problems maybe Content-Length in Chrome using UpdatePanels. I don't know.

Comment: Maybe F5 Balanced issues, but I haven't probes.